# Move JQuery function to inside a function then access it from more than one function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

Hi I've had a trawl through the various search engine results and not coming up with anything that's pointing me in the right direction, so hopefully someone on here can help me.

I'm a noob where Javascript / JQuery is concerned so go easy please.

Problem: I'm presently calling a JQuery DatePicker function from clicking on a Textbox, this works great. You click on the Textbox, select a date , it puts it in to the Textbox. Big Tick.

But I need to also call the same function by clicking on an image too. I thought I would do this by calling a .click function

```
$("endDateImage").click(datePickerFunc);
```

that calls the original JQuery

```
$("#endDatepicker").datepicker({ // options set here });
```

which I've tried to re-write as a new function

```
function datePickerFunc() {
        $().datepicker({
            // options set here
        })
    };
```

but this is where it all goes wrong, I can't seem to find out / work out how to write the new function so I can call it from any number of $("ID of control").click(datePickerFunc);

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

--UPDATE-- in reply to the below answers:

The following works:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="endDatepicker" runat="server" Text="10/10/2013" Width="65px"></asp:TextBox>
```

with

```
$("#endDatepicker").datepicker({
 dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
 defaultDate: "+1w",
 changeMonth: true,
 numberOfMonths: 2,
 onClose: function (selectedDate) {
$("#startDatepicker").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);} });
```

but the same asp:TextBox ID .... click on doesn't work with the following:

```
$("#endDatePicker").click(datePickerFunc);

function datePickerFunc() {
        $(this).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#startDatepicker").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
            }
        })
    };
```

(note i've gone back to my working TextBox click on 1st, then will try with an image after).

Is my version of Jquery ok? am I missing referencing something? thanks

Coding is in HTML 5 / C# / css /JQuery version 1.9.1.js & ui version 
1.10.3.

Cheers

Trev.

Comment: are you trying to open the existing datepicker from the image. If so use oriignal selector deatpicker created with and show method http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-show

Comment: In answer to your question, I want to click on a TextBox (input) or an image and display a datepicker, then put in the TextBox the selected date. Whether the TextBox itself or the image was clicked, I want the selected date to go in the TextBox. Thanks.

Comment: create a live demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i'll try it in future. I've still not found out why I can't get the suggested to work but im now making the image a background of the DIV and just making the TextBox the onclick event to pop up the calender. this is working fine. thanks all.

Comment: just an update, due to asp.net server side code renaming textboxes I'm now using $(".endDatepicker") instead and setting a class called "endDatePicker" on the textbox rather than using ID.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `this`, as it will refer to the clicked element:

```
$("#endDateImage").click(datePickerFunc);
$("#foo").click(datePickerFunc);

function datePickerFunc() {
    $(this).datepicker({
        // options set here
    })
};
```

This will result in both the `#endDateImage` and `#foo` elements having their own instance of `datepicker` created on them.

Comment: datepicker bound to an image? sure about that?

Comment: @charlietfl positive. You can use any element as the trigger for the datepicker control. You would just need to handle the selection event and do what you need with the value.

Comment: knew you could do what you ant using `altField` I gues come to think of it I've used one ona  Div before...my bad. I got impression OP wanted to open existing one...scope not 100% clear

Comment: @charlieftl No problemo :)

Comment: Hi and thanks to you both for your links / comments. I did try $(this) but deleted it from my original post as it doesn't work for me. I have also tried the "show" method as per the link, that's not working either.

Comment: Ok, been playing with code last hour and sort of got it working but not for an image. I Started a new .aspx document, copy / pasted the code from here http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ and tried it, it works but I have to click the input then click outside it, then click it again before the datepicker appears! Anyway, thought 'ok its working' so copy /pasted the code above and with two inputs called the same as endDateImage and foo, it works (but I still have to click in, click out then in again) but if I try to use an image it ignores my click. Same for a <Div> with id foo, tried a <P>.